# Ubuntu no longer boots with kernel 5.15.0-53-generic - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: boot, kernel, radeon, gpu-driver

As of today, my Ubuntu 22.04 PC gets as far as grub, but choosing the default option of `"Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-53-generic"` leads to a blank and unresponsive screen after only a few lines of kernel messages.

Choosing `"Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic"` works.

This is a PC which has been working fine for years: a Ryzen 7 3700X, with AMD Radeon RX5700 GPU.

How can I investigate what has changed between 5.15.0-52-generic and 5.15.0-53-generic?

Edit:

The following line appears to appear in `/var/log/syslog` during unsuccessful boots:

`[    4.426566] [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.`

Edit 2:

The following solution does not work: [Disables amd gpu kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166054/disables-amd-gpu-kernel) :  it creates a corrupt image on the screen instead of a black screen, but otherwise remains frozen.

Edit 3:

This bug report looks like the same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1996740

Comment: Same issue. Had to select the previous kernel to boot.

Answer (score 0):

As per the bug report linked in the question, this has now been resolved. The fix is available through:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```