# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS GUI does not work with 5.15.0-88-generic

Tags: kernel, graphics, 22.04, gui

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a HP laptop 15-db0598sa. It is fully up to date with the latest drivers etc, but I cannot boot into 5.15.0-88-generic, as the GUI gives a black screen with the occasional flashing white line when I choose it from the GRUB menu.

The previous version I have on there (kernel 5.15.0-84-generic) boots correctly and the GUI does work. I did think it was an issue with the previous version (5.15.0-86-generic), but upgrading has not changed behaviour.

How would I go about diagnosing what the issue is with graphics in the new version of the kernel?

I note that a previous kernel version has had issues with graphics [Ubuntu no longer boots with kernel 5.15.0-53-generic - how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441829/ubuntu-no-longer-boots-with-kernel-5-15-0-53-generic-how-to-troubleshoot), but this is now with 5.15.0-88-generic.

EDIT: I have found this bug on launchpad affecting AMD Radeon graphics: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2042772, which this laptop has

Second edit: It still occurs with 5.15.0-89-generic kernel.

Comment: Due to that fact that I'm on 20.04.6 (*$ cat /etc/os-release*), fully updated, but "still" running 5.13.0-52-generic: I'd guess that you have manually installed kernels which do not fully support your system software. See - https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=ubuntu+kernel+versions - I'd say you have installed the 22.04 kernel, which may well cause your trouble.

Comment: It is 22.04.3 that I'm running - thanks for pointing that out.